# Download de arquivo com Laravel 5.3

Tags: sistema-de-arquivos, laravel-5.3

preciso disponibilizar arquivos PDF para download. Não sei se pelo menos estou no caminho certo, mas estou tendo um erro que indica que o arquivo não existe.
Meu controller está da seguinte forma:

```
public function  download($id,Request $request)
{
    $title = 'Download - file';
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        return URL::to('file/'. $id . '/download');
    }
    $file = File::findOrfail($id);
    $fileNome = $file->nome;
    $dir= public_path()."\\$file->user_id\\$fileNome";
    $headers = array(
      'Content-Type: application/pdf',
      );
    $baixar = Response::download($dir, $fileNome, $headers);
    return view('file.download',compact('title','baixar'));
}
```

O erro é:

> FileNotFoundException in File.php line 37: The file
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\pontualContabi\public\1\boleto_cassio.pdf" does not
>   exist in File.php line 37 at
>   File->__construct('C:\xampp\htdocs\pontualContabi\public\1\boleto_cassio.pdf')
>   in BinaryFileResponse.php line 94

O caminho do arquivo está correto. Não estou entendendo o motivo deste erro. Será que alguém pode ajudar ?

Comment: Pegue a URL e cole no navegador. Veja se abre o arquivo. `C:\xampp\htdocs\pontualContabi\public\1\boleto_cassio.pdf`

Comment: "Arquivo não encontrado".
Quando colo o link direto no navegador ele vira

file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/pontualContabi/public/1/boleto_cassio.pdf

Comment: Então não existe o arquivo :p

Comment: Sim, o arquivo existe. Esta na pasta.

Comment: Vai na pasta dele pelo explorer e veja em que pasta esse arquivo realmente está. Acredita no erro. Se está falando que não encontrou é porquê está errado. Clica na barra de endereço na pasta do arquivo e copia o endereço e cola aqui.

Comment: O arquivo está lá. Inclusive eu uso outra maneira pra acessar o arquivo. que não sei se é indicado por motivos de segurança. Eu chamo um modal com o link para o arquivo, dessa forma eu consigo.
Eu só não sei se dessa forma é a ais indicada para realizar essa tarefa.